# Counterexample for the Second fundamental theorem of Asset Pricing

Tags: arbitrage, asset-pricing

so the The Second Fundamental Theorem of Asset Pricing says:

> An arbitrage-free market (S,B) consisting of a collection of stocks S and a risk-free bond B is complete if and only if there exists a unique risk-neutral measure that is equivalent to P and has numeraire B.

I want to construct an example of a one-period market model in discrete time that is complete but doesn't have a risk-neutral measure (showing that "arbitrage-free" as a condition can't be omitted).

So, more formally, I have a market $(\{\omega_1,\omega_2\},\mathcal{P}(\{\omega_1,\omega_2\}), P)$ with $B_t=1$ for $t=0,1$ (Bond) and price processs $(S_t^d)_{t=0,1}$ , $d=1,...,D$.

Now I have to find prices such that it is not arbitragefree but complete and doesn't have a unique risk-neutral measure. Can someone help?